# extend an instance at runtime

Tags: python, inheritance, instance

This question was denied on StackExchange, and I haven't found an answer yet on StackOverflow.

**Note:** the code *does* work, and I'm asking about ideas, better options and opinions (performance, reliability) to extend class instances at runtime.

For example, let's say my original class is Foo and I want to "extend it" with Bar.

The specific constraints I have now is:

- Python 2 compatible, even if I'm curious about Python 3 specifics if there are any
- I get an object from a different library I would like to add functionalities to (note: this is an "old style class")
- I need it to keep it's parents so isinstance(instance, Foo) keep working
- It must not re-run the **init** from the first class (there are stateful connections)
- It would be nice to be able to test it's inheritance on the "new" class (ie: isinstance(instance, Bar))

I wonder if there is something to do with **new**, **metaclass**, or mix-ins. But I did not achieve anything with those yet.

### What I tried

Using as a base:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self): return 'foo'

class Bar:
    def bar(self): return self.foo() + 'bar'

foo = Foo()
```

#### create a new object referring to the previous

It works, but it creates a new object and I wanted to do without doing so (and I think that the test is a useless overhead):

```
class Bar(Foo, object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.__foo = foo
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__foo, name)
        except:
            raise AttributeError
    def bar(self):
        return self.foo() + 'bar'

bar.foo() # OK
bar.bar() # OK
isinstance(bar, Foo) # OK
isinstance(bar, Bar) # OK
```

#### updating the instance dictionary

Almost worked, but Bar does not appear in inheritance:

```
foo.__class__.__dict__.update(Bar.__dict__)
foo.bar()            # does work
isinstance(foo, Foo) # True
isinstance(foo, Bar) # False :(
```

#### using types.MethodType

Almost, but Bar does not appear in inheritance and I have to test if the attribute I'm patching is a callable or not:

```
for k, v in Bar.__dict__.iteritems():
    if callable(v):
        setattr(foo, k, types.MethodType(v, foo))

foo.foo() # OK
foo.bar() # OK
isinstance(foo, Foo) # OK
isinstance(foo, Bar) # False
```

Please enlighten me.

Comment: should the first example not be `class Bar(Foo):`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham < I indented to make the first example the simplest as possible and I didn't assume `Bar` **had** to be a `Foo` subclass (if there was a way to change the `instance.__class__.__bases__`). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAVEAT:  This is not clean programming!  But you knew that :-)

The easiest thing to do is to make Bar be a subclass of Foo, and then dynamically change the type of your instance:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self): return 'foo'

class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self): return self.foo() + 'bar'

foo = Foo()

foo.__class__ = Bar

print foo.bar()
```

In response to a question in a comment:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo(self): return 'foo'
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     def bar(self): return self.foo() + 'bar'
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> 
>>> foo.__class__ = Bar
>>> 
>>> print foo.bar()
foobar
>>> isinstance(foo, Bar)
True
>>> isinstance(foo, Foo)
True
```

In response to another comment:  yes, it really is that easy :)

Comment: !@# that's so simple I didn't even think about it. Let me keep the question open another day or two to see if anybody comes with weird solutions because I'm curious.

Answer (score 3):

If you want isinstance to work you can add Bar to `Foo.__bases__`:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self): return 'foo'

class Bar:
    def bar(self): return self.foo() + 'bar'

foo = Foo()
Foo.__bases__ = Foo.__bases__ + (Bar,)

print(foo.bar())
print isinstance(foo, Foo) 
print(isinstance(foo, Bar))
foobar
True
True
```

Comment: This changes every instance of Foo to also be an instance of Bar.  This may certainly be desired in some cases, but I read the original question as being about changing particular instances rather than the class in general.

Comment: I like the fact it'll patch all further instances of `Foo` without doing anything! And it even patches already instanciated objects. Wonderful.

Comment: @bufh, as patrick pointed out, it may or may not be what you want as the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it may or not be the desired behaviour and I'm happy to read different solutions for differents scenarios, so do not delete your answer @PatrickMaupin! My question was not explicit on this point.